# Drop pandas row if column contains non-alpha values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to drop a row from a dataframe if `location` column has some non-alpha values as well as empty values.

Input:

[image: input df]

Expected output:

[image: output df]

I tried as below. But it only removes non-alpha characters.

```
test = data.location.str.replace('[^a-zA-Z]', '')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expected output, you should also account for commas and spaces.

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check for letters, commas, and spaces:

- `[a-zA-Z]` makes sure there's at least one letter (because you don't want rows with only commas/spaces)
- `[a-zA-Z, ]*` then matches any number of letters/commas/spaces

Then select the matching rows either with direct [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```py
test = data[data.location.str.contains('^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z, ]*$')]
```

Or by passing to [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```py
test = data.loc[data.location.str.contains('^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z, ]*$')]
```

Output:

```
                  location
1  England, United Kingdom
2                    KENYA
3          Kampala, Uganda
4           Rio de Janeiro
```

Answer (score 2):

`DataFrame.str.replace` just replace the pattern, and not removing it. What you are looking for is `DataFrame.str.contains` [(documentation)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), which returns a series of true / false for each row (whether `location` contains the non-alpha chars). With that boolean indexing (a true / false series for each row) you can use `DataFrame.drop` to remove rows:

```py
test.drop(data.location.str.contains('[^a-zA-Z]'), inplace=True)
```